# control RSS feeds

Tags: 8, feeds

How can I control which RSS feeds Drupal generates automatically?
I would like to send out my site's content but choose which categories of posts are included in the RSS. I am using Drupal 8.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal 8 comes with some default RSS feeds created using views

**frontpage feed** can be edited here `admin/structure/views/view/frontpage/edit/feed_1` which provides the feed accessed from this url `domain.test/rss.xml`

and **taxonomy feed** can be edited here `/admin/structure/views/view/taxonomy_term/edit/feed_1` which provides the feed accessed from this url `domain.test/taxonomy/term/TERMID/feed` where TERMID is the term id for each taxonomy term

You can modify those or create your own views based on those to accomplish what you need